# Looking for suggestions to replace openCV's blob detector

Tags: python, opencv, convolution

I have some code written in python that is used to clean up an image and then use a blob detector to identify blobs in the cleared up image. While this works efficiently for pictures that are small for example 549x549 pixels. It gets very slow when doing large pictures such as those that are 14790x13856 pixels. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to make the blob detector (oepncv) faster or a replacement library that is faster?

edit:

add pic:
Here is an example of a picture:
[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED5eR.png)

It's about that size^, but about 667x bigger

I already have the code written and on a small scale there are no errors

```
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 0
params.maxThreshold = 255

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 0
params.maxArea = 35

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0

# Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0

# Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0

# Create a detector with the parameters
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
keypoints = detector.detect(third)
ImgPoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(third, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, `255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
```

The result is a picture (tiff) that I save and there are no error messages.

Comment: Without an image it is hard to know what you have to work with. Please post your images to some free hosting and put the URL here. One possibility would be to use contours, though I have no direct experience on speed performance between the two.

Comment: @Orion - do you need the original resolution for the analysis? Would it be possible to simply scale down the image so it is a more manageable size? I'm currently working on some large (2200x3300) images, and I wouldn't want to get any bigger because cv2 is already getting a bit sluggish with contours/blobs/cannys

Comment: @PeptideWitch Yea, I need it to about full resolution. This is because the blobs I have to detect are only about 10-50 pixels in Area.

Comment: @Orion I wonder if it's not worth splitting your mega-image up into smaller chunks, and then conducting analysis on those smaller portions. You may want to also think about overlapping sections in case the boundaries between those chunks contain blobs too. IMO, there's not going to be another function in OpenCv that can handle these bigger files easily (I'm guessing they're 100+MB each, if .tiff?) Perhaps someone else has a suggestion. You could also try scikit-learn blob detection, or look into libvips - never used it before, though

Comment: @PeptideWitch Thanks, I think ill try the splitting idea first. It seems the most appropriate especially since even the full image right now is only 1/30th of what it will have to handle. Thanks!